# numpy.random.rand not giving me the right shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to get a 3 x 3 array that looks like this:

```
[
    [ 0.76720544  0.1254068   0.08350556],
    [-0.265288   -0.28945529 -0.57703701],
    [ 0.12194653 -0.3044894   0.46754351]
]
```

using `numpy.random.rand(3 * 3) - 0.5`, but instead I get a 1 x 9 array that looks like this:

```
[ 0.2221102, -0.25766852, -0.04060757, 0.23138759, 0.4081494, -0.1911101, 0.1737616, 0.19768079, 0.28941601]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `numpy.random.rand(3, 3)`, not `numpy.random.rand(3 * 3)`. `rand` takes the dimensions of the output as individual positional arguments.

Remember that Python evaluates the arguments going into the function, so the only possible interpretation of `numpy.random.rand(3 * 3)` is that it's the same as `numpy.random.rand(9)`, which is what you got: a one-dimensional array of length `9`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is:

```
numpy.random.rand(3,3) - 0.5  # , as seperator between dimension-sizes!
```

Look at the docs of [rand](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html).

The signature reads:

> numpy.random.rand(d0, d1, ..., dn)